# htaccess redirect all page to https except when cookie is set

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cookies, https

By default i need the site to redirect everything to HTTPS, except ONLY when a cookie is set to "admin". When the cookie is set to "admin" i need the whole site to be http, not just some pages. So far i have read a lot of entries here and there but non actually worked. Here is what i have on htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (admin)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.org/$1 [R,L]
```

also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookie-name=admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie-name=admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.org/$1 [R,L]
```

It still redirects me to https even when the cookie is already set. is there a way to this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.org/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. I'm getting : This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: @Amporu sorry, you don't need that [OR] flag